# How to make verification message alert by jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have this code for view cats of my script

```
<table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<td class="td1" width="70%" align="center">title</td>
<td class="td2" width="30%" align="center">Delete</td>
</tr>
<?php
    $select_cats = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cats");
    $num_cats = $select_cats->num_rows;
    while ($rows_cats = $select_cats->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $id_cat         = $rows_cats ['id'];
        $title_cat      = $rows_cats ['title'];
        ?>
            <tr rel="<? echo $id_cat; ?>">
                <td class="td1" width="70%" align="center"><a class="link2" href="../cat-<? echo $id_cat; ?>.html" target="_blank"><? echo $title_cat ; ?></a></td>
                <td class="td2" width="30%" align="center">
                <a rel="<? echo $id_cat; ?>" class="deletecat" href="#">Delete Cat</a>
                <span class="loading" rel="<? echo $id_cat; ?>"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <?
    }
?>
```

and i use this jquery code for delete cat

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".deletecat") .click(function(){
var id_cat = $(this).attr('rel');
var s = {
"id_cat":id_cat
}
$.ajax({
url:'action/delete_cat.php',
type:'POST',
data:s,
beforeSend: function (){
        $(".loading[rel="+id_cat+"]") .html("<img src=\"../style/img/load.gif\" alt=\"Loading ....\" />");
        },
success:function(data){
$("tr[rel="+id_cat+"]") .fadeOut();
}
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

i want to make verification message in dialog box by `alert();` has two options 
if click Yes do jquery code and if click no close dialog box

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) dialog to ask the user to confirm the action, if not confirmed exit without the jQuery action like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".deletecat").click(function () {

        //show the confirmation
        if(!confirm('do you want to proceed')){
            return 
        }

        var id_cat = $(this).attr('rel');
        var s = {
            "id_cat": id_cat
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'action/delete_cat.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: s,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".loading[rel=" + id_cat + "]").html("<img src=\"../style/img/load.gif\" alt=\"Loading ....\" />");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("tr[rel=" + id_cat + "]").fadeOut();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code before the ajax connection,

```
if (!confirm("Are You Sure?")) {
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".deletecat") .click(function(){

confirm here
if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")){
 return; // i.e return if user selects no. otherwise proceed.
}

var id_cat = $(this).attr('rel');
var s = {
 "id_cat":id_cat
}
$.ajax({
url:'action/delete_cat.php',
type:'POST',
data:s,
beforeSend: function (){
$(".loading[rel="+id_cat+"]") .html("<img src=\"../style/img/load.gif\"       alt=\"Loading ....\" />");
    },
success:function(data){
$("tr[rel="+id_cat+"]") .fadeOut();
}
 });
 return false;
});
});
```